# What is the best way to avoid keyError when using python dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
    for target, source ,in zip(self.tCorpus, self.fCorpus):
        #print(target, source)
        self.pairLength[len(target), len(source)] += 1
```

It's obvious that this will give me a key error since I did not initialize the key `len(target), len(source)` before using this. I know I could use default dict to avoid this kind of error, but I am not sure how to avoid it in this particular case. Is there a way to prevent keyerror and increment values for `len(target), len(source)` ?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Neither your variables nor your indices make any sense without some background info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `collections.defaultdict` or `collections.Counter`. Any of these three will work:

```
self.pairLength = collections.defaultdict(int)
self.pairLength = collections.defaultdict(lambda: 0)
self.pairLength = collections.Counter()
```

`collections.Counter` has the added advantage of giving you `self.pairLength.most_common(10)`, which may be useful for your particular application.

If for whatever reason you can't use a new container, just make sure the key exists before doing anything:

```
for target, source ,in zip(self.tCorpus, self.fCorpus):
    key = (len(target), len(source))

    if key not in self.pairLength:
        self.pairLength[key] = 0

    self.pairLength[key] += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the get () with default value param:
`self.pairLength.get((len(target), len(source)),0)+=1`

Answer (score 0):

Normally, I would recommend the `setdefault` method; it takes the key and a default value as arguments. If the key is not found it is assigned the default value and that value is also returned. If the key does exist, the default value is ignored and normal lookup takes place:

```
a = {}
a.setdefault(7, []).append(1)
a
# {7: [1]}
a.setdefault(7, []).append(2)
a
# {7: [1, 2]}
```

In your case that doesn't work because we are not changing the value but reassigning it. Therefore

```
a[key] = a.get(key, 0) + 1
```

The difference between `get` and `setdefault` is that get does not assign the default value in case of key miss. It always leaves the dict unchanged. But since we have to explicitly reassign anyway - numbers being immutable - that is appropriate here.